# Detect text input and clear other textbox

Tags: jquery

I have a textbox called startDateTextBox. When a user types a value in this box I would like the other textboxes to clear.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function ($){
       $('#startDateTextBox').on("textchange",function(){ 
           $("#startExciseNumberTextBox").val('');
           $("#endExciseNumberTextBox").val('');
       });
 });
```

Comment: Use `keypress` instead of `textchange`.

Comment: `input` instead of `textchange`

Comment: the other two specific inputs, or all inputs within the document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clear the other text boxes is easy all you have to do is listen for a keypress, keyup, paste, or keydown events and make sure the startDateTextBox is not empty

Note: if you use ID on the other textboxes code will only work on the first ID textboxes so user CLASS attribute instead of ID to avoid that from happening.

use the code below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#startDateTextBox").on('keypress keyup keydown paste', function(){

if($(this).val().trim() != ""){

   //clear the other textboxes here 

   $("#startExciseNumberTextBox").val('');
  $("#endExciseNumberTextBox").val('');

}
})

})
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a `changetext` event, there is [`change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) and [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) events.

```js
$('#startDateTextBox').on('input', clearInputs);

function clearInputs(e) {
  $(':text').not(this).val('');
}
```

```html
<input id='startDateTextBox' type='text'><br>
<input value='content' type='text'><br>
<input value='content' type='text'><br>
<input value='content' type='text'><br>
<input value='content' type='text'><br>
<input value='content' type='text'><br>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  $('#startDateTextBox').on("change", function() {
    $("input").not(this).val('');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="startDateTextBox" />
<input />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the JQuery implementation:

```
$("input").change(function(){
    alert("The text has been changed.");
});
```

Or, expanding on your own code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#startDateTextBox').on('change', function() {
        //do stuff
    });
});
```